# HttpURLConnection не реагирует на setRequestProperty

Tags: java, android, rest, httpurlconnection

Есть Rest-сервис, написан на Java. Отрывок кода прилагаю.
    `@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})`Пытаюсь из Android'a обратиться на адрес службы, все работает.
Но вот тип ответа установить не получается. Если в коде сверху первым идет 
    `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`     то ответ получает в формате JSON, если меняю местами, и первый идет     `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML`     то получаем XML. Вопрос в следующем, почему не срабатывает переключения в самом клиенте Android, через установке параметров запроса     `conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");`     ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что, когда вы делаете `conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml")`, вы говорите что отправляете запрос типа application/xml.
Чтобы сказать сервису в каком формате вы ждете ответа, надо передать ему заголовок Accept (`conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")`)

Comment: Большое спасибо. Каждый раз после таких вопросов, удивляюсь тем кто пишет документацию:) Почему нельзя писать в документации все понятнее:)

Comment: Пожалуйста :) отметьте тогда мой ответ как правильный